# How do I separate a long string into 3 different strings using a separator in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this string: `500 Minutes + Unlimited Text + Your Choice of Data`

I want to separate it in 3 different strings and store it in 3 different variables, having data as

1) 500 Minutes 2) Unlimited text 3) Your choice of data.

I want to use `+` as the separator in this process, whenever `+` comes, create a new variable for the following text, until one more `+` comes.

Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know there are exactly three variables:

```
text = "500 Minutes + Unlimited Text + Your Choice of Data"
a, b, c = [part.strip() for part in text.split('+')]
print a
print b
print c
```

prints:

```
500 Minutes
Unlimited Text
Your Choice of Data
```

Comment: slightly better case: `a, b, c = map(str.strip, text.split('+'))`

Comment: @defuz -- Is that slightly better?  I'm not convinced ;-)

Comment: @defuz - even better `a, b, c = text.split(' + ')` - if the formatting is clean.

Comment: just checked: it appears not, my version is slower. @eumiro, right, if spaces are required.

Comment: Just in case I would go for...: `try: a, b, c = (el.strip() for el in text.split('+'))` and `except ValueError as e: pass # do something`

Comment: What if I have only 1 `+` i.e. 2 variables can be made Or I don't have any `+` i.e only 1 variable can be made?

Comment: I am trying out `Try` and `except` for those cases.